# Parents applying together for UK visit visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

My parents are both permanent residents of USA and are applying for their first UK visit visa to come and see me (their daughter, EU citizen).

My father is in full-time employment with a reputable company in the US and good regular income. Mom is a housewife and not in employment. They have a joint account where my dad receives salary and they also keep their joint savings.

My Dad is going to pay for my mom's visit. However, they have to each fill separate applications. So both of them are asked about their savings and since they have a joint account, they are not sure what they should write? Should they each mention the total sum in their joint account? or divide the total in half and each of them write that amount?

Also, there is a question as how much money you are going to spend in this visit. My dad was wondering if the number he puts down in his applications should be just the money for him or the total of sum for him and my mother? If he puts, let's say 5000 for both of them, then how should my mother answer the same question? It is a bit confusing as my mom is stating that she is dependent on my dad but still they have to each fill two separate applications.

I would be thankful if you can advise.